# Is it possible to set the colour of padding in gtk?

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3

I am aware that it is usually considered bad practice to modify colours within a gtk app, and that usually you respect the user designated theme but is it possible? I just cant get it to work. I am using gtk2hs, a haskell wrapper for gtk. I can easily set colors for all other widgets, just not this one.

Edit: I wanted padding at the top of my textview, so I placed the textview within an alignment widget and set the padding on that. I have tried setting bg, fg, base and text colours for each possible state for the textview, its parent (the alignment widget), and the alignment widgets parent, a vbox.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some more specific information about what you're trying to do that doesn't work, so people have some context in which to help you.

Comment: Which widget are you trying to change the colour of? What properties are you trying/have tried?